# Getting the input from one argument and only one argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

This is a function from my script:

[image: This is a function from my script]

This is just a function from a script I am writing. Basically I am trying to get the user to only type one argument if it is more than one it has to output an error and if it doesn't have an argument that is also an error. When I run the script I get:

> a syntax error at the elif [ $# -ne 1]; then] line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: We also recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) as a first stop for any bash syntax errors

Comment: Based on the requirements, it looks like you should be using -eq instead of -ne.  Right? You want to do something if they enter a  single parameter.  Also, the syntax of your if statement and your elif statement are inconsistent.  It looks like your if statement is missing a semi-colon between the test and the then.

Comment: Replace image with its text.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, your code is missing a semi in the first if statement and the -ne should be a -eq.  Here is the working code and a set of test cases:

```
$ cat student_check.sh
Student_Check()  {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ] ;  then 
    echo "No file specified"
  elif [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo success
  else
    echo "Invalid input"
    exit
  fi
}

echo Test 0 
Student_Check
echo Test 1 
Student_Check 1 
echo Test 2 
Student_Check 1 2


$ ./student_check.sh
Test 0
No file specified
Test 1
success
Test 2
Invalid input
```